# arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 001270: Consolidating the data failed

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-server, publishing, error-001270

I am working on PuTTY and trying to create service definition file in server. My Python script is creating .sddraft but I am receiving 'Consolidating the data failed' error when I run stage service script. 
I already checked the following link and fixed my issues. 
 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000002r001270

```
import arcpy

wrkspc = '/home/gis/arcgis/server/arcpy/arcpy/idtech/Example/'
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(wrkspc + 'test.mxd')

service = 'test'
sddraft = wrkspc + service + '.sddraft'
sd = wrkspc + service + '.sd'

analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft , service, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES')
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
```

Comment: FWIW, I just ran into this and my issue was that my MXD was 10.7.1 and I was trying to publish it in a 10.6.1 environment. Saved a copy of it down to 10.6 via File > Save a Copy and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when my drive (c:) filled up and it had nowhere to write the result!  Took me a long time to realise this